# Aggregate group on related property with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to perform a Mongodb aggregate that will allow me to group on items located in the lookup object and count based upon items located in a subdocument, as an example:

Customer:

```
- first: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 35, required: true},
- middle: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 35, required: true},
- last: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 35, required: true},
- email_address: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 7, maxlength: 255, required: true},
- city: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 75, required: true},
- state: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 75, required: true},
- zipcode: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 75, required: true}
```

Order:

```
- customer: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer'},
- [OrderLineItem]
```

Product:

```
- name: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 35, required: true},
- manufacturer: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 5, maxlength: 35, required: true}, 
- cost: {type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true},
- current_inventory: {type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true}
```

OrderLineItem:

```
- product: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
- quantity: {type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true},
- total_cost: {type: Schema.Types.Number, required: true}
```

Get the total count of products purchased by zipcode:

```
this.order.aggregate([
{$lookup: {from: "Customer", localField: "customer", foreignField: "_id", as: "customerObj"}},
{$group : {_id : {zipCode: "$customerObj.zipcode", products: "not sure what goes here...."}, total: { $count: "not sure what goes here..." }}}
])
```

For the example above, I would like to get a report of the total count of products purchased by zip code.  As I am trying to build my aggregate I am missing how it should be coded for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator will return an "array" of matching items in all cases. Since the relationship is `1:1` for the customer you can easily address the element via [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/).

Your question did not name the schema property which contains the array of `OrderLineItem` so I'm assuming `"order_lines"` below, change to whatever you are actually using.

```
Order.aggregate([
  // lookup the customer detail
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "customers",
    "localField": "customer",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "customer"
  }},
  // Group by zip
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$customer.zipcode", 0 ] },
    "total_qty": { "$sum": "$order_lines.quantity" }
  }}
])
```

If you wanted something from the `"Product"` detail itself, like the `"manufacturer"` and needed you use that as part of the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), then it becomes necessary to do another [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), and again the detail is in an array with the same `1:1` relationship. But you would need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `"order_lines"` first:

```
Order.aggregate([
  // lookup the customer detail
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "customers",
    "localField": "customer",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "customer"
  }},

  // $unwind the order lines
  { "$unwind": "$order_lines" },

  // lookup the product detail
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "products",
    "localField": "order_lines.product",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "order_lines.product"
  }},

  // Group by zip by manufacturer
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "zip": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$customer.zipcode", 0 ] },
      "manufacturer": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$order_lines.product.manufactuer", 0 ] }
    },
    "total_qty": { "$sum": "$order_lines.quantity" }
  }}
])
```

You might note that usage of [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) does not change here despite that in only one case the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation was used on the `"order_lines"` array. This is because as of MongoDB 3.2 you can notate an array comprising of the values of an inner property directly, so this:

```
"items": [{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 2, "b": 3 }]
```

When referenced as `"$items.a"` becomes:

```
[1,2]
```

Also the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator was changed so it would also accept an "array" of items as well as accumulate within a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

---

**NOTE** the naming convention used on collections. By default Mongoose uses a convention that given singular model name i.e `"Customer"` will be "pluralized" down to be `"products"` as the actual collection name. The `$lookup` operator runs on the server and not in your client code that knows about models, therefore the only thing the server knows about is collections.

You may have deliberately named your collection to use in the declaration of the mongoose model like:

```
 mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema, "customer")
```

which would then mean that the collection is referenced by it's correct name. But generally most people don't do this, so it is important to make the distinction.